# basic questions about DynamicArrayStack

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, stack

I learned they Dynamic Array Stack today, and the professor upload the template code online. Here is the link if you are interested to take a look at http://ideone.com/oXe2t1 . But there are some parts on the code that I do not understand.

```
// I did not know how he comes up with the (3 * _size)
void pop() {
    assert(!is_empty());
    _size--;
    if (_capacity > (3 * _size))
        resize();
}
```

and then on the resize()

```
//how does he know that the max capacity will be equal to either (_size * 2)
// or DYNAMIC_ARRAYED_STACK_MIN_CAPACITY
void resize() {
    _capacity = max(_size * 2, DYNAMIC_ARRAYED_STACK_MIN_CAPACITY);
    unique_ptr<E[]> new_array(new E[_capacity]);
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        new_array[i] = _elements[i];
    _elements.swap(new_array);
}
```

Comment: Those numbers are very likely just good but arbitrary choices. Why don't you ask him?

Comment: I will, but since he posted the code after class, so I won't see him until next week. That's why I bring it up here and ask you guys about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm retyping and reposting my answer, having looked at the code you posted in the link.

The answer is, the professor didn't **know** to set these values; they're just what he chose.

Just to make sure we know our terms: `_capacity` is how much the stack *can* hold, while _size is how much the stack *is currently holding*.  The goal in making a dynamic stack is to always try to minimize the amount of memory that is wasted and minimize the amount of reallocations of the memory.  You trade one off in favor of the other.

Your professor made this stack with the following rules:

- Start with a capacity of 1.  (This is the defined `DYNAMIC_ARRAYED_STACK_MIN_CAPACITY` value.)
- If the capacity is ever 3x that of the size or higher, resize it to be 2x the size.
- If the size = the capacity, resize the capacity to be 2x the size.

You have to have a minimum capacity.  Some implementations (like the Microsoft .NET standard) actually set your minimum to about 10, and then resize from there.  By setting a slightly bigger value, you avoid resizing your array for the first few entries, but in this instance (probably so you can see how the logic works), it's set to 1.  That means that as soon as you push one element, you have to resize.  You have to have a max of `DYNAMIC_ARRAYED_STACK_MIN_CAPACITY` and 2x size because the size will initially be 0.  If you didn't have the minimum, your capacity would be 0 as well, and this would cause errors.

Making the capacity double the size is also arbitrary.  You could make it 100x the size, if you prefer.  That means you'll do far fewer resizes - but you'll waste a lot of memory.  2 is probably a pretty good number to balance resizing vs. wastage.

The threshold at which to trigger shrinking the array is also arbitrary.  By setting it to 3x, that leaves a lot of room to pop elements without having to resize every time.  That is somewhat wasteful of memory, but not too bad.

As you use these concepts, you can set the numbers to whatever you need.  Aside from the fact that the MIN is set to 1, these are pretty good standard numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, even clearer and more information than my professor said in more than an hour in the lecture !!!!